# PopupMenu in Gtk#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#, popupmenu

I have a Gtk scrolled window that I'm trying to attach a PopupMenuHandler function too like so:

```
this.scrolledwindow1.PopupMenu += HandlePopupMenu;
```

and the HandlePopupMenu looks like so:

```
[GLib.ConnectBefore]
public void HandlePopupMenu(object o, PopupMenuArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("test");
   Gtk.Menu mbox = new Gtk.Menu();
   Gtk.MenuItem Test = new Gtk.MenuItem("test");
   Test.Activated += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Console.WriteLine("test");
   };
   mbox.Append(Test);
   mbox.ShowAll();
   mbox.Popup();    
}
```

My problem is that this event never gets called when I right click on the scrolled window. which I'm assuming it should based on [this](http://mono-project.com/GtkSharpNotificationIcon). There is only one other event handling the ScrollEvent, and nothing handling keyboard or mouse buttons. Can anybody tell my why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't add popup menu to `GtkScrolledWindow` but to it's content. Most of it's events is disabled by default and generally, users really don't want any popups on their scroll bars.

2) `PopupMenu` signal is only invoked for keyboard shortcuts (Shift+F10 or Menu button), not mouse right clicks. `GtkStatusIcon` isn't derived from `GtkWidget` so it works differently.

You need to implement `ButtonPressEvent` and `PopupMenu` signals to get both mouse and keyboard to show the menu. [GTK+ documentation on implementing popup menu (C, not C# though).](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-migrating-checklist.html#checklist-popup-menu)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd already started implementing the ButtonPressEvent but was curious about the PopUpMenu event.